# Twitter Log In Button Greyed Out

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-login

I'm trying to implement logging in with twitter in my app. I just came across news that states that Fabric was sold to Google. I am not using Fabric in my application. Instead I am using the twitter core sdk `com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1` . I try to initialise Twitter but the login button is still greyed out with this code:

```
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.twitter_key), getString(R.string.twitter_secret)))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);
```

I see the following error output in my logcat
`E/Twitter: Must initialize Twitter before using getInstance()`
How can I go about this error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To solve the problem, I took my `Twitter.initialize(TwitterConfig)` statement before Android's `setContentView()` method and problem solved:
**Sample Code**

```
 TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
            .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.twitter_key), getString(R.string.twitter_secret)))
            .debug(true)
            .build();
    Twitter.initialize(config);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_twitter);
    mLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {}
```

Comment: The way you set it up helps me. The setContentView() after the initialize process. After I change this, the button not grey anymore. Thanks.

Comment: glad it has helped, will now make it accepted answer, dont forget to vote up @QuartZ

Comment: Also dont forget that note : // Inflate layout (must be done after Twitter is configured) from docs https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/TwitterLoginActivity.java#L57